# Javascript call methods from nested objects in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I believe `this` is pointing to the wrong object but cannot figure out how to loop through an `object` and on each iteration, call a `method` from that nested `object`.

Example:

```
var obj = {
  one: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'one',
    getName: function() {
      return this.name();
    }
  },
  two: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'two',
    getName: function() {
      return this.name();
    }
  }
};

for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(key.getName());
}
```

This returns the error `Object one has no method getName`. How can I access that nested `method`?

Comment: Not sure if this fits what you're doing, but it looks like your outer `obj` should be an array of objects, not an object of objects

Comment: That would work in this case but the snippet is stripped down. A object is required for the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the inner object using the key. Also, return `name` as a property, not a method call

```js
var obj = {
  one: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'one',
    getName: function() {
      return this.name;
    }
  },
  two: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'two',
    getName: function() {
      return this.name;
    }
  }
};

for (var key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key].getName());
}
```